# Experiences comsuming REST-ful services in Grails 2.3?

Tags: rest, grails, client

We are about to take on a large project implemented in Grails (2.3.7). The application makes heavy use of many different (end-points as well) REST-ful webservices. We are of course interested in using what is considered to be "best standards" (at least currently).

We are currently considering:
 - Using the Groovy HTTP-builder
 - Using the "REST Client builder" plugin

Any other we should consider and what are your experiences using the above mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

I have used both http://grails.org/plugin/rest and http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder and both provide a nice wrapper around HTTP Builder library. The "rest" plugin provides dynamic methods for you if you like using that syntax. I prefer REST client builder though. Both are easy to work with.

Comment: Thinking of using the "grails-datastore-rest-client" directly instead of via the plugin. It seems the plugin is no longer maintained, at that it merely references this package in the buildconfig. Any comments on that?

Comment: I noticed that Graeme has wrapped the functionality up into a new plugin. It looks to me like the usage is syntactically the same as the REST Client Builder, so I expect that the will be additional features to take advantage of as well. The plugin has high ratings so far.

Comment: Afaik i don't think rest-client-builder uses HTTP builder.. Agree?